# Find the latest kubernetes available version of eks using Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I am using Terraform to check if latest Kubernetes version installed on EKS cluster.
There is way to find desired latest AMI for EC2 using data sources

```
data "aws_ami" "latest_ami" {
most_recent = True
owners = ["amazon"]

filter {
    name = "name"
    values = ["amazon-ami-hvm*"]
}
}
```

I can get the current version of running cluster

```
data "aws_eks_cluster" "example" {
name = "example"
}
output "current_version" {
value = data.aws_eks_cluster.example.version
}
```

Looking for way to compare it with latest available version

Comment: With latest available version on AWS or with the latest stable?

Comment: available version on AWS.